How to prove the result of the following integral?
How to prove that
$$
\int _0^{\infty }\frac{K\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x+1}}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{x+1}}e^{-x}{\rm d}x =
\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{e \pi }  K_{1/4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$

where $K(x)$ in the integral is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind (EllipticK[x] in Mathematica)
and $K_{\frac{1}{4}}(x)$ in the RHS is  the modified Bessel function
of the second kind (BesselK[1/4, x] in Mathematica).

Mathematica cannot calculate the above integral, but the following
Mathematica code
NIntegrate[
  EllipticK[1/2 - 1/2/Sqrt[x + 1]] (x + 1)^(-1/4) Exp[-x], {x, 
   0, \[Infinity]}, PrecisionGoal -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 100] - 
 1/2 Sqrt[E  Pi] BesselK[1/4, 1/2]

shows that they are of the same value.
Update: How do I find the result?
I tried to evaluate the following integral in two ways:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2-g x^4}dx$$

On the one hand, using Integrate[Exp[-x^2 - g  x^4], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], Mathematica gives $\frac{e^{\left.\frac{1}{8}\right/g} K_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{1}{8 g}\right)}{2 \sqrt{g}}$.

On the other hand, we can expand the interaction part in a power series:


$$\begin{aligned}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}xe^{-x^2-g x^4}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}xe^{-x^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-g x^4)^k}{k!}\end{aligned}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sqrt{\pi}\frac{(-g)^k(4k)!}{2^{4k}(2k)!k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k g^k$$
However, the summation $f(x)=\sum a_k x^k$ does not converge. But we can apply the Borel summation to calculate $g(x)=\sum a_n x^n/n!$ and transform the result to $f(x)$ by $f(x)=\int_0^\infty g(b x)e^{-b}$. The following code shows the procedure:
Sum[Integrate[
  SeriesCoefficient[Exp[-x^2 - g  x^4], {g, 0, k}] g^k/
    k!, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], {k, 0, \[Infinity]}]

Assuming[g > 0, 
 Integrate[(% /. g -> x  g) Exp[-x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]]

Mathematica can do the summation but cannot do the next integration. However, we expect the final result to be the same as the result of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}xe^{-x^2-g x^4}$, which means that
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{2 e^{-x} K\left(\frac{\sqrt{4 g x+1}-1}{2 \sqrt{4 g x+1}}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt[4]{4 g
   x+1}} \, dx=\frac{e^{\left.\frac{1}{8}\right/g} K_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{1}{8 g}\right)}{2 \sqrt{g}} $$
Let $g=1/4$ we can get the integral. The above process is not particularly rigorous. I want to know if there is a rigorous method to prove this integral result.

@ClaudeLeibovici Link to the definitions added.

Just kidding : change $100$ by $1000$; the numbers differ a lot $(3.125\times 10^{-613})$

How did you find the rhs ? Just curious

An equivalent result (obtained by doing an appropriate u-substitution) is $$\int_0^1 e^{-1/u^2}u^{-5/2}K\left(\frac{1-u}{2}\right)~du=\frac14 \sqrt{\pi/e}K_{1/4}(1/2)$$

The modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_v(x)$ may be defined via the Tricomi's function:
$$ K_v(x) = \sqrt{\pi}(2x)^ve^{-x}U\left(\frac{1}{2}+v;1+2v;2x \right) \quad v\geq 0  $$
if we put $\displaystyle v=\frac{1}{4}, x=\frac{1}{2} $
$$ K_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)= \sqrt{\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}}U\left(\frac{3}{4};\frac{3}{2};1 \right) \tag{1} $$
Tricomi's function has the following integral representation:
$$U\left(a,b,z\right)=z^{c-a}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-zt}t^{c-1}{{}_{2}{\mathbf{F}}_{1}}\left(a,a-b+1;c;-t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t $$
With $\displaystyle a=\frac{3}{4}, b=\frac{3}{2}, c=1, z=1$
$$U\left(\frac{3}{4};\frac{3}{2};1 \right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}{{}_{2}{\mathbf{F}}_{1}}\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4};1;-t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t \tag{2} $$
The Gauss hypergeometric function satisfies the following linear transformation:
$${}_2\mathbf{F}_1\left({a,b\atop c};z\right)=(1-z)^{-b}{}_2\mathbf{F}_1\left({c-a,b\atop c};\frac{z}{z-1}\right)$$
if we put $\displaystyle a=\frac{3}{4}, b=\frac{1}{4}, c=1, z=-t$
$${}_2\mathbf{F}_1\left({\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4}\atop 1};-t\right)=(1+t)^{-\frac{1}{4}}{}_2\mathbf{F}_1\left({\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\atop 1};\frac{t}{t+1}\right) \tag{3}$$
It also satisfies the following quadratic transformation:
$${}_2\mathbf{F}_1\left({a,b\atop\frac{1}{2}(a+b+1)};z\right)={}_2\mathbf{F}_2\left({\frac{1}{2}a,\frac{1}{2}b\atop\frac{1}{2}(a+b+1)};4z(1-z)\right) $$
With $\displaystyle a=\frac{1}{2}, b = \frac{1}{2}, 4z(1-z) = \frac{t}{t+1} $
$${}_2\mathbf{F}_1\left({\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\atop 1};\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t+1}}\right)={}_2\mathbf{F}_1\left({\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4} \atop 1};\frac{t}{t+1}\right) \tag{4}$$
However, it is well known that
$$ K(m) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\theta }{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2(\theta)}} = \frac{\pi}{2}{}_2\mathbf{F}_1\left({\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\atop 1};m\right) $$
where $K(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.
Hence
$$\frac{2}{\pi} K \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t+1}}\right) = {}_2\mathbf{F}_1\left({\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\atop 1};\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t+1}}\right) \tag{5}$$
Summarizing:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{e \pi }  K_{1/4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) &=&  \pi U\left(\frac{3}{4};\frac{3}{2};1 \right)  \quad \textrm{ from (1)} \\
&=& \pi \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}{{}_{2}{\mathbf{F}}_{1}}\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4};1;-t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t \quad \textrm{ from (2)}\\
&=& \pi \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t} (1+t)^{-\frac{1}{4}}{}_2\mathbf{F}_1\left({\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\atop 1};\frac{t}{t+1}\right) \mathrm{d}t \quad \textrm{ from (3)}\\
&=& \pi \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t} (1+t)^{-\frac{1}{4}}{}_2\mathbf{F}_1\left({\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\atop 1};\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t+1}}\right) \mathrm{d}t \quad \textrm{ from (4)}\\
&=&  \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t} (1+t)^{-\frac{1}{4}}2K \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t+1}}\right)  \mathrm{d}t \quad \textrm{ from (5)}
\end{eqnarray*}
